# Form doesnt send values with jquery and post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

These is my code and when i click on the button doesnt alert the form correctly i dont know if im doing something wrong because of the hurry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                var form = $("#form").serialize();
                alert(form);
                $.post("action.php", form, function(data){
                    $("#response").html(data);
                });
            });                
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <table>
            <tr colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <td><b>Formulario</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C&oacute;digo Alumno:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="alumno" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C&oacute;dido curso:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="curso"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C&oacute;digo profesor:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="profesor"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Correo profesor:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="correo"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Descripci&oacute;n:</td>
                <td><textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="button" value="Enviar"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot see the values in the server side and appears

```
Notice: Undefined index: alumno in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\action.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: curso in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\action.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: profesor in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\action.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: descripcion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\action.php on line 16
```

please

Comment: you are doing something cause you are in a hurry, this is not the page producing the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `name` attribute to your input controls like this

```
<input type="text" id="correo" name="correo" /></td>
```

then your `action.php` will get the parameter you want.